# distinct item for each date

Tags: sql, distinct

for each date, i have different items with unique ID, how to create a table to show each date with distinct item in each day?

```
date |item | Trade ID
1    |A    | 123
2    |A    | 124
1    |A    | 125
3    |B    | 126
1    |A    | 127
2    |A    | 128
3    |C    | 129
1    |A    | 130
```

desired results

```
date |item
1    |A    
2    |A    
3    |B    
3    |C
```

i tried the following code, but i got an error msg
select date, distinct item
from mytable
it says found "distinct"  expecting an identifier found a keyword

thank you!

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Why is date 1 always combined with A? Is this a coincidence in your sample data? Can one date occur with two different items? If yes: what to do in this situation? If no: change your data model (i.e. normalize it).

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct date, item
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `DISTINCT` like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       date,
       item
       FROM elbat;
```

Or with `GROUP BY` like:

```
SELECT date,
       item
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY date,
                item;
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` doesn't work on certain columns, but on the whole row you are selecting. It has to follow the `SELECT` keyword directly.

```
select distinct date, item from mytable;
```